# Should I care about dart's memory jitter?

Tags: animation, dart, flutter, garbage-collection

In flutter development, I want to implement custom UI with animationController and customPainter. But in the meantime, I found `memory jitter` is very serious.

[image]

In the Android world, we need to care about `memory jitter` because of the Java `stop world`. However, in the dart world especially flutter, I don't know should I call my attention to this.

I know dart use the non-lock garbage-collection, but will too much garbage-collection slow the application response?

Comment: [Dart's GC is supposed to be particularly fast for allocating many short-lived objects](https://medium.com/flutter-io/flutter-dont-fear-the-garbage-collector-d69b3ff1ca30), which is what the Flutter framework does.

Comment: @jamesdlin so just put the memory jitter aside? It seems jitter is a normal phenomenon.

Comment: Unless you're actually observing jank, then I don't think you should worry about it.